# SSRS 2008 - Date parameter default not making it to the report server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a date range parameter(s) in a report.  The query has in the where clause:

```
BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

and in the report, these parameters exist, and set to DateTime datatype.  @Startdate has a default hardcoded as 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM.  I tried using =Today() for the @EndDate, and it works in BIDS, but gets to the report server as no default.  I also tried creating a report variable, and setting the default to that, but go an error stating I can't set parameter defaults to report variables.

So, how do I get my @Enddate to default to today's date in the report server?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting and deploying the report from the report server; sounds like it's not recognizing some of your changed properties.  Should that not work, view the report in Report Manager, and go into the management/properties page on it - you should be able to see (and, if necessary, set) the default value.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that, no help.  I ended up creating a new dataset with a simple query to get todays date (GETDATE), then set that as the parameter default.  Works like a charm.